# Is Inspire Greatness (Bard) the only way to gain explicit temporary Hit Dice?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, bard, hit-dice

The bard's [Inspire Greatness](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/Bard/#TOC-Inspire-Greatness-Su-) ability adds 2d10 hit dice to a character for a short period of time.

The trait [Magical Knack](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/magic-traits/magical-knack/) gives you bonus caster levels that cannot exceed your current hit dice.

Combining the two you effectively receive +2 caster levels.

Other than Bardic inspiration, are there any other spells or abilities (even ability drain) that grant you explicit bonus hit dice?

I have not been able to find any in my Google searches or database searches (but then again, I'm not a coder able to script such things).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Sorrowful](https://www.aonprd.com/ArchetypeDisplay.aspx?FixedName=Bard%20Sorrowsoul) bard archetype also grants bonus HD as well, but those shouldn't stack with your *Inspire Greatness* (despite the confusing wording):

> At 12th level, a sorrowsoul can use his lyric sorrow ability in conjunction with inspire greatness to grant himself **3 bonus Hit Dice**, a +3 competence bonus on attack rolls, and a +2 competence bonus on Fortitude saves; if he does so, inspire greatness only affects him, not any other allies.

Other than that, that is the only ability in the game that grants bonus HD and still keep your intelligence and/or ability to still be affected by morale effects and mind-affecting abilities (think undead templates).

Answer (score 1):

[Master Performer](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Master%20Performer) and [Grandmaster Performer](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Grand%20Master%20Performer) will increase the bonus hit dice granted by Inspire Greatness. Note that while they were made by Paizo, they are for factions in Pathfinder Society. Therefore, for non-PFS games, your GM may or may not allow them.